# Accessing new windows via Cypress is not happening in its current version

Tags: cypress

I have written testcase to buy laptop from website

```
describe("laptop from website ", function () {


    beforeEach(function () {
        cy.visit('https://www.amazon.in/', {
            onBeforeLoad(win) {
                cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowOpen')
            }
        })
    })


    it("Search and Buy Laptop From amazon", function () {

        cy.get('#searchDropdownBox').select("All Categories", { force: true });
        cy.get('#twotabsearchtextbox').type("Laptop i7 processor, 8/16 GB RAM ");
        cy.get('.nav-search-submit > .nav-input').click();
        cy.get('[data-index="0"] > :nth-child(1) > [data-component-type="s-impression-logger"] > div.rush-component > .s-include-content-margin > .a-spacing-medium > :nth-child(2) > .sg-col-16-of-24 > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(1) > .sg-col-4-of-12 > .sg-col-inner > :nth-child(1) > .a-size-mini > .a-link-normal > .a-size-medium').click();
        cy.visit('https://www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_mtf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A079189026U6M04NWR9FI&url=%2FHP-Pavilion-15-6-inch-Windows-Graphics%2Fdp%2FB07F64D9XJ%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fkeywords%3D%2522Laptop%2Bi7%2Bprocessor%252C%2B8%252F16%2BGB%2BRAM%26qid%3D1562849061%26s%3Dgateway%26smid%3DA14CZOWI0VEHLG%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1562849061&id=6042596282297865&widgetName=sp_mtf')

});




})
```

I want to automate new window: this line of code

```
    cy.visit('https://www.amazon.in/gp/slredirect/picassoRedirect.html/ref=pa_sp_mtf_aps_sr_pg1_1?ie=UTF8&adId=A079189026U6M04NWR9FI&url=%2FHP-Pavilion-15-6-inch-Windows-Graphics%2Fdp%2FB07F64D9XJ%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fkeywords%3D%2522Laptop%2Bi7%2Bprocessor%252C%2B8%252F16%2BGB%2BRAM%26qid%3D1562849061%26s%3Dgateway%26smid%3DA14CZOWI0VEHLG%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26psc%3D1&qualifier=1562849061&id=6042596282297865&widgetName=sp_mtf')
```

is opening in new tab.

Comment: What's the point of the first part of the test if you then just navigate straight to the item page? And please be more specific about what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress can't handle new tabs or windows. So this is simple not possible (maybe in the future it is).